# What does it mean when one says "$B$ has no limit point in $A$"?

Tags: general-topology

If $B$ is a subset of a set $A$, what does the sentence "$B$ has no limit points in $A$" mean? I am aware that $x$ is a limit point of $A$, if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $(U-\{x\})\cap A$ is non-empty.

Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It means that if $x$ is a limit point of $B$, then $x$ is not an element of $A$.  or conversely, if $x$ is an element of $A$, then it is not a limit point of $B$.

This would include the case where $B$ has no limit points at all.

Without more context it's hard to say why this might be important.

Comment: $x$ can be a limit point of $B$ without being an element of $B$.  Consider $A = (0,1)$ and $B = \{1/n : n\in\Bbb Z\}$.  Then $B\subset A$, and $B$ has a limit point, namely 0, which is not in $A$.

Comment: Ahh, I see guys. I was reading a theorem in Complex Analysis that said that a holomorphic function $f$ on a domain $D$ is either identically $0$ or the set $\{z \in D | f(z) = 0\}$ has no limit points in $D$. I was confused as to what this meant. I think I have a better idea now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @merry LaTeX tip: Use `\{z \in D \mid f(z)=0\}` or `\{z \in D \mathrel| f(z)=0\}` to get correct spacing around the set builder bar.

Comment: @merry I think you should consider asking a new question, specifically about this theorem. I don't know about the significance of "no limit points in $D$" in the context of complex analysis. Could the function's set of zero points have a limit point outside of $D$?  I don't know.

Comment: Okay! I shall think about that. Thanks for the answer though. It answered my current question.
@kahen Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Giving an example may be helpful for you.

> **Example:** Let $X=\mathbb R$ with usual topology. $A=\{x\in \mathbb R: x > 0\} \subseteq X$ and $B=\{1, \frac12, \frac13,... \frac1n,...\} \subset A$. It is not difficult to see that $B$ has no limit points in $A$ since the unique limit point 0 of $B$ is not in $A$.